# Retrieving the "snapped to" element using jQuery UI draggable with snap enabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI's draggable, with 'snap' enabled and set to select a class of elements. This means that the draggable snaps to the edges of (for example) a class called **.general**.

When the draggable is snapping to an element of class **.general**, is it possible to find or select that exact 'snapped to' element?

Comment: Were you able to find the answer to your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out about the "snapped to" element for jQuery UI draggable elements on snap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177867/how-to-find-out-about-the-snapped-to-element-for-jquery-ui-draggable-elements-o)

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this, which will harvest the elements it is snapping to:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {
            var snappedTo = $.map($(this).data('draggable').snapElements, function (element) {
                if (element.snapping) { return element; }
            });
   }
});
```